# ReactJS: Axios' async request is returning 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, async-await, axios

I'm doing a little project using the movie DB API is ReactJs, and I have problems to use async functions, i'm making the api calls in many parts of projects an worked in all of them, but now it's not working.

My axios config:

```
export default axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/',
  params: {
    api_key: process.env.REACT_APP_API,
  },
});
```

In my container I have this

```
const { setMenuSelected } = useContext(MovieContext);
const [movie, setMovie] = useState({})
const [recommendations, setRecommendations] = useState([]);
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)

useEffect(() => {
  animateScroll.scrollToTop({ smooth: true });
  setMenuSelected('');
  getMovieRecommendations(setRecommendations, match.params.id, setIsLoading);
  setMovie(getMovieDetails(match.params.id, setMovie));
}, [match.params.id, recommendations, isLoading]);
```

I'm fetching the data in other file just to organize the project

```
export const getMovieRecommendations = async (
  setRecommendations,
  movieId,
  setIsLoading) => {
  const res = await api.get(`/movie/${movieId}/recommendations`);
  setRecommendations(res.results);
  setIsLoading(false);
}
```

And to render the movie list I'm passing the recommendations to my component that only use map to render each movie,

```
<MovieList header={'Recommentadion'} movieList={recommendations} />
```

But the app allways crash saying "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined", i looked in the network properties in the chrome and my request is finishing with no erros.

Update:

return of `console.log(JSON.stringify(res))` I removed the results itens so it wouldn't get too big

```
{
  "data":{
    "page":1,
    "results":[
      {},
      {},
      {},
      {},
      {},
      {},
      {},
      {},
      {},
      {},
      {},
      {},
      {},
      {},
      {},
      {},
      {},
      {},
      {},
      {}
    ],
    "total_pages":2,
    "total_results":40
  },
  "status":200,
  "statusText":"",
  "headers":{
    "cache-control":"public, max-age=14400",
    "content-type":"application/json;charset=utf-8",
    "etag":"W/\"56ca661f28e43dc3dd2ce41816b517c5\""
  },
  "config":{
    "transformRequest":{

    },
    "transformResponse":{

    },
    "timeout":0,
    "xsrfCookieName":"XSRF-TOKEN",
    "xsrfHeaderName":"X-XSRF-TOKEN",
    "maxContentLength":-1,
    "headers":{
      "Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"
    },
    "method":"get",
    "baseURL":"https://api.themoviedb.org/3/",
    "params":{
      "api_key":"fe5b485ed12153ca357c3275cfad6c5c"
    },
    "url":"https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/399121/recommendations"
  },
  "request":{

  }
}
```

Comment: can you show us your MovieList component as well?

Comment: This is related to axios actually. You have to fetch res.data.results rather than res.results. Debug and see if you are really getting that property or not. And try checking for res.data rather than res.results.

Comment: Have you missed this `await api.get`? I guess you mean `await axios.get(..)`

Comment: @DhavalChheda this really works, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing:

```
const res = await api.get(`/movie/${movieId}/recommendations`);
console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
```

This will print the whole JSON object into a string in the console. Since you're getting undefined and no error, you are most likely accessing the JSON object incorrectly. By printing out the contents this will show you what your JSON object looks like so you can get to the 'results' property successfully.

Comment: Can you update the question with the returned JSON? I suspect you're just accessing the '.results' property incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

### Explain axios.create & Example

axios.create is for initial.. (config)

`const axios = Axios.create({  withCredentials: false/true });`

Now, create a function using axios like that:

```
function get(...args) {
  return axios.get(...args)
}
```

and call as you write:

```
const res = await get(`/movie/${movieId}/recommendations`);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this help you.
you should export your axios config like this:

```
const APIClient = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/',
  params: {
    api_key: process.env.REACT_APP_API,
  }
});

export default APIClient;
```

and then import it to fetch data in another file:

```
import  APIClient  from "YOUR AXIOS CONFIG FILE";

  export const getMovieRecommendations = async (movieId) => {
  const { data } = await APIClient.get(`/movie/${movieId}/recommendations`);
  return data;
}
```

In your container set this:

```
const { setMenuSelected } = useContext(MovieContext);
const [movie, setMovie] = useState({})
const [recommendations, setRecommendations] = useState([]);
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)

const getList=async(movieId)=>{
const res = await getMovieRecommendations(movieId);
  setRecommendations(res.results);
  setIsLoading(false);
}

useEffect(() => {
  animateScroll.scrollToTop({ smooth: true });
  setMenuSelected('');
  getList(match.params.id);
  setMovie(getMovieDetails(match.params.id, setMovie));
}, [match.params.id, recommendations, isLoading]);
```

Comment: I thinks that i'll do this, this way I don't need to pass functions to others.

Comment: are you sure that "results" is in your returned data from api?

Comment: consider that axios always return a "data" param.